# Multiple Views Same Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Course Model which goes the controller and views in a restful way.

For my Course show, it is fully featured. I now want another Course show which will have a simplify page and it like to the original course show.

How can I implement this? I want it to be restful, so in my controller there should only be show, update, index, etc.

Should I create another controller that have an different name from the Model? E.g. Course2?

Comment: Why don't you just add another action to the existing controller? There's no law that says you can only use REST-ful actions in a controller.

Comment: There is no law but a restful app should not have that. There is no law that says you cant put model logic inside the views, but it is code smell.

Comment: Would the action for the controller be the same? ex. `@course = Course.all` for `index` If so, what if you checked for a `simple` parameter and rendered a partial based on that. Erb example - `<% if params[:simple] == 'true' %> <%= render 'simple' %> <% else %> <%= render 'full' %> <% end %>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is an admin view vs. public view, I would have entirely different namespaces for two different RESTful controllers. Or if you think you're going have this summary vs. full view thing a lot, create namespaces based on that distinction.

Another option is to encoded the differences in a single ERB template. Or you could actually have the show action render different templates from the same action using some conditional logic.

Without more context though, I can't really say what's the best option. I am personally against creating non-RESTful actions unless it's really going to be a one-off thing. Non-RESTful actions tend to get out of hand in my experience and controllers can get really ugly and unintuitive.

Comment: It is the same context instructor context so the namespace is the same. The summary page has less things in the controller that is why I may not want to use the one controller with multiple view.

Answer (score 1):

If this is truly just displaying a subset or a different arrangement of the same information, then I think this is a job for the view.  At most the controller can use the same action, but select a different view to render, such as might be done if the user wanted to see html vs plain text.

The controllers job is to interpret the model and the views job is to collect and display information. I think you would be concerned about the view having logic in it if you what you describe as a "summary" were more than just a subset of the info,  for example if you started to calculate the distances being traveled or how long it would take or how much it would cost based on the data that is provided, then that would be bad.

So I this is just a subset, then I would suggest either rendering partials based on some variable set by your controller, or if organization of the display needs to be substantially difference, then the controller can select a different template to render.